# How to color a shape in Babylon.js?

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

Working off the "Basic Scene" example on babylonjs-playground.com [here](https://www.babylonjs-playground.com/), I am trying to do a simple modification on the color of the sphere.

Here is my attempt, which can be run interactively:

https://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#95BNBS

Here is the code:

```
var createScene = function () {

    // The original example, without comments:
    var scene = new BABYLON.Scene(engine);
    var camera = new BABYLON.FreeCamera("camera1", new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 5, -10), scene);
    camera.setTarget(BABYLON.Vector3.Zero());
    camera.attachControl(canvas, true);
    var light = new BABYLON.HemisphericLight("light1", new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 1, 0), scene);
    light.intensity = 0.7;
    var sphere = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateSphere("sphere1", 16, 2, scene);
    sphere.position.y = 1;
    var ground = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateGround("ground1", 6, 6, 2, scene);

    // My attempt to color the sphere
    var material = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial(scene);
    material.alpha = 1;
    material.diffuseColor = new BABYLON.Color3(1,0,0);
    scene.material = material;

    return scene;

};
```

My attempt to add the colored material to the sphere has no effect.

I also tried to look for color-related attributes on the sphere object:

```
Object.keys(sphere).filter((key) => return key.includes("Color") )
// => "outlineColor", "overlayColor", "_useVertexColors", "edgesColor"
```

Except for `_useVertexColors`, all of these seem to be color objects, but changing them has no effect:

```
sphere.overlayColor.g = 1;
sphere.outlineColor.g = 1;
sphere.edgesColor.g = 1;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're pretty close. You are setting a color correctly with `diffuseColor` but you aren't actually adding it specifically to your sphere.

Your sphere object is stored in `sphere` so what you need to do is you need to set the `material` you created  on `sphere` and not on `scene`.

```
// My attempt to color the sphere
var material = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial(scene);
material.alpha = 1;
material.diffuseColor = new BABYLON.Color3(1.0, 0.2, 0.7);
sphere.material = material; // <--
```

See this [tutorial](http://doc.babylonjs.com/tutorials/materials)

Comment: thank you, i had an aha moment with this about the exact time you answered. However I was making the same mistake in both my actual code and in the babylon playground example, so even though it's a silly mistake it may still be helpful for others.

Comment: glad you figured it out :)